# Getting body-Parser is deprecated Warning In Vs code and not Able to get Body tried to use inbuilt body-parser of express

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser, req

[image]

Below Is Code Of `app.js` file

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // set our port
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors');
var indexRouter = require("./server/routes/index");
var http = require('http').Server(app);
const path = require('path')

const Licence = require('./server/CronJob/CronJob');

http.listen(port);

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000
}));


// parse application/json
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0");
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/build")));

app.use(indexRouter);

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html'), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
})

// Licence.licenceExpire();

console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port); // shoutout to the user

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Version

express: ^4.17.1,
body-parser: ^1.19.0

and also used suggestion given in below [blog](https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c)

**update**

I have used inbuilt body-parser but getting same error again here is the screenshot of function of inbuilt body-parser

[image]

Comment: You don't need external body-parser . Body parser is now included in Express.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From 4.16.0+ body-parser is inbuilt in express

Use http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded())
```

https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0

> The express.json() and express.urlencoded() middleware have been added to provide request body parsing support out-of-the-box. This uses the expressjs/body-parser module module underneath, so apps that are currently requiring the module separately can switch to the built-in parsers.

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/b7420f8dc5c8b17a277c9e50d72bbaf3086a3900

> This deprecates the generic bodyParser() middleware export that
> parses both json and urlencoded. The "all" middleware is very
> confusing, because it makes it sound like it parses all bodyes,
> though it does not do multipart, which is a common body type. Also,
> the arguments for the two different middleware are starting to
> overlap and it's hard to configure then when done this way.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using this code

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

then you can replace this code with

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

and if you are using

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

then replace with

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use body-parser

Getting request body is now builtin with `express` So, you can simply use

```
app.use(express.json()) //For JSON requests
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

directly from express

You can uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**Then you can simply get the POST content from `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or just like this, for string JSON body

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```